# Computed properties cannot store a value but hold a value, what is hold and how to hold?

Tags: swift, properties

Quote from "Swift Apprentice second edition page 225":

> Properties(computed) **hold** values that you can get and set. Methods perform work

Quote from "Swift official document":

> In addition to stored properties, classes, structures, and enumerations can define computed properties, which do not actually **store** a value

One says "store", another one says "hold". I get a bit confused about the computed properties, what exactly the computed properties do not store a value means? Is it means the system will not assign any memory space to save the value and will only hold it. But what's the hold means? you can't hold something in nowhere, you need maybe a box to hold something, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example from the documentation

```
struct Cuboid {
    var width = 0.0, height = 0.0, depth = 0.0
    var volume: Double {
        return width * height * depth
    }
}
```

`volume` is never stored in memory. Whenever the getter is called the result of the multiplication is returned dynamically like a math operation in a local scope.

The official Apple documentation does not use the term `hold` at all.

Comment: the declaration clause "var volume: Double " defines a value, it reserves a space in memory  and marks it as "volume" (like a box), the memory size is set to the size where it can store a value up to the largest Double number (predefined), this is how I understand what is a declaration. But if a computed value had been declared, is that means those steps will also implement but it will not assign the return value into the "box", it will create the box return the value and destroy the box. This is my guess. Or there is no "box" at all

Comment: There is no box at all and it does neither reserve space in memory nor define a value. Prove it by pasting the struct somewhere, create an instance and set a breakpoint. Only `width`, `height` and `depth` are in memory of the struct. See also the definition of a stored property: *In its simplest form, a stored property is a constant or variable that is stored as part of an instance of a particular class or structure*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation